# Различные виды меха разн(ых/ой) длины и цвета" -?

Tags: согласование

Как правильно: "различные виды меха разн**ых** длины и цвета" или "различные виды меха разн**ой** длины и цвета"?

Answer (score 2):

Мне всё не нравится.
Меньше всего нравится "разных длины и цвета". Вроде как длина и цвет сравнивается друг с другом, сравните: "разные *Петя и Маша"*.

Поэтому если из двух зол выбирать, то *"разной длины и цвета"*.

Но при этом так же не нравится "различные виды" при том, что "длина и цвет" - разные. Скорее уж наоборот, "виды" они и так различные (=различающиеся, на то они и виды), а вот разные - это значит, что более одного, это понятно.

Вообще, если можно поменять побольше, то ***"меха разного вида, длины и цвета"***. Не знаю, как в плане точности передачи авторского смысла и профессиональных моментов, но по части литературного стиля так будет лучше всего.

(+) Обновление 11.03.2016

> Согласен со всем, только вот "разные (различные) виды меха", по-моему,
>   не совсем то же, что "меха разного вида". В последнем случае кажется,
>   что речь идёт о внешнем виде товара, то есть о том, что они выглядят
>   по-разному. Или тут своя терминология, к которой я не привык?

(Артём Луговой)

Я не говорю, что одно и тоже. Но "различные виды", если речь идет не о видах из окна, вызывает у меня большие сомнения. "Вид" уже представляет собой некий таксон, классификационную единицу, различные они **по определению**, одинаковых не бывает. Поэтому "различные" избыточно. А "разные" здесь понимается как "более одного", тавтологичности нет.

(++)
Терминологии не знаю, исхожу из общего понимания. Возможно как раз и ошибаюсь.

Comment: Согласен со всем, только вот "разные (различные) виды меха", по-моему, не совсем то же, что "меха разного вида". В последнем случае кажется, что речь идёт о внешнем виде товара, то есть о том, что они выглядят по-разному. Или тут своя терминология, к которой я не привык?

Comment: Да-да, ваша логика, что "разные" лучше чем "различные", мне кажется совершенно правильно.